# MouseListener on editable JavaFX ComboBox

Tags: combobox, javafx, javafx-8

MouseEvent is not working for JavaFX ComboBox when it is set to editable. It is working well on Non editable ComboBox. Is there any way to set MouseEvent on editable ComboBox?

```
package editablecombobox;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EditableComboBox extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.setEditable(true);

    combo.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {    //adding MouseEvent on ComboBox
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("MOUSE PRESSED!!!");
        }

    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(combo);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

setOnMousePressed is not working.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code so that we can help better.

Comment: Which `MouseEvent` are you talking in particular? I have tried the `onMouseEntered` and few others, all of them work.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha i have edited my question. I have created a dummy application. onMousePressed is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are just interested in the Editable TextField area of the `ComboBox`. You need to add the `MouseListener` to the editor(`TextField`) of the `ComboBox`. Try using :

```
combo.getEditor().setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {    
     @Override
     public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("MOUSE PRESSED!!!");
     }
});
```

Comment: 1. `getEditor` may return `null`, you should check that probably by registering for changes on `editorProperty()` and 2. the editor is a child of the ComboBox control element, so the mouse events should be delegated upwards. If that is not the case, there is probably another issue here (maybe even JavaFX Bug)?

Comment: It will never return `null`, try to go through the `editorProperty()` method of the ComboBox class

Comment: You are right, when digging through the source code, the editor gets intialized alongside its property, but the API docs explicitely state: "The editor is null if the ComboBox is not editable." So this might change and break in future versions.

Comment: IMHO, the OP is intelligent enough to make a check if he is removing the `editable` property from the ComboBox. *We are not here to write codes for them...*

Comment: That's why I did neither downvote your answer nor said that it is wrong, I just wanted to mention this. I thought this is what the comments are for, after all..